# increase image size without loosing quality - JS

Tags: javascript, html, electron

i'm using electron to make an app that get application icons.
so i used `app.getFileIcon()` to get the icon and with `icon.toDataURL()` and pass the image url with an event to index.html

and it works fine but when i increase the size of the image it gets blurry because the max size of icon by `app.getFileIcon()` can only be 32px(or 48 in MacOs or linux)

this is how it looks like (before height increase)

[image]

after height increase

[image]

Main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, shell } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('public/index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// Get File Icons ------------------------------------------------

const filePath = path.normalize("C:\\Users\\hamid\\Desktop\\DualTouch\\NordVPN.lnk");
const realPath = shell.readShortcutLink(filePath).target

app.getFileIcon(realPath).then(icon => {

  const ImgUrl = icon.toDataURL()
  ipcMain.on('ImgUrl-request', (event)=>{
    event.sender.send('ImgUrl-reply', ImgUrl)
  })
  writeFileSync('icon.png', icon.toPNG())

}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>DualTouch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script>
  const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

  ipcRenderer.send('ImgUrl-request');

  ipcRenderer.on('ImgUrl-reply', function (event, args) {
    document.write(`<img src='${args}' />`)
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Icon Url](https://imgur.com/download/EDKUrLT/)

Comment: image sizes cannot be increased except they are svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add information to an image that does not exist, but there are some really good upscaler's theses days, especially those based on AI.

For example going to this website -> https://bigjpg.com/ I was able to upscale your image to look like this ->

[image: Upscaled Image]

A quick search for tools for AI upscaling bring this up  https://github.com/topics/upscaling , so maybe one of these options might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the image size is inversely proportional to the quality, i.e the exposure of the picture elements of the image. So in order to get greater quality, I would suggest you get an image with more pixels and greater resolution.